# Slow performance when XOR'ing bytes

Tags: c#, arrays, xor

I am experiencing some not so satisfactory performance when XOR'ing byte arrays.

Not that it's absolutely terrible, but i was wondering if there was some way to get some better performance.

I was thinking maybe utilizing more of the cpu's registry for each xor. But i dont how exactly to go about doing this.

Here is my function responsible for XOR'ing.

```
internal void TransformBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, long inputOffset, int inputCount,byte[] outputBuffer, int outputOffset, byte[] counter, int counterOffset, byte[] key)
    {
        using (var encryptor = Aes.CreateEncryptor(key, zeroIV))
        {
            int offs = 0;
            int blocks = inputCount + counterOffset > 16 ? ((inputCount + counterOffset + 16 - 1) / 16) : 1;
            var counterBuffer = new byte[16 * blocks];

            for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < counter.Length; j++)
                {
                    counterBuffer[offs++] = counter[j];
                }
                // Increment counter by one
                for (var k = counter.Length - 1; k >= 0; k--)
                {
                    if (++counter[k] != 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
            var keyBytesBuffer = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(counterBuffer, 0, counterBuffer.Length);
            for (var i = 0; i < inputCount; i++)
            {
                outputBuffer[outputOffset + i] = (byte)(inputBuffer[inputOffset + i] ^ keyBytesBuffer[i + counterOffset]);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you narrowed it down to that specific code? It would seem to me that the k loop could be accomplished with math alone. Also, Array.Copy() might be a candidate to replace the i/j loop.

Comment: *"I was thinking maybe utilizing more of the cpu's registry for each xor. But i dont how exactly to go about doing this"* - really? More cpu registry? Do you mean "how to make my PC faster"? Measure performance (by profiling) first, find and look at critical (slow or most used) parts, can you improve them? Maybe there is flaw in algorithm?